# Java namespace collision undetected in maven dependency

Tags: java, maven

What should happen in a maven project, when there are **two dependencies** containing **same class name** (with **same package name**, but **different implementation**) ?
I was expecting a build failure. But build got succeeded.

In the below example, `main.launcher.MainLauncher` uses  `mvn.dep.namespace.demo.SampleServiceImpl` which is present both in **dependency1** and **dependency2**.

Upon execution, I see `SampleServiceImpl called from Dependency1` as output.

```
// Class from Dependency 1**
package mvn.dep.namespace.demo;

public class SampleServiceImpl {
    public String printMe() { return "SampleServiceImpl called from Dependency1"; }
}
```

```
// Class from Dependency 2**
package mvn.dep.namespace.demo;

public class SampleServiceImpl {
    public String printMe() { return "SampleServiceImpl called from Dependency2"; }
}
```

```
//Class in main project using SampleServiceImpl 
package main.launcher;

import mvn.dep.namespace.demo.SampleServiceImpl;
public class MainLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new SampleServiceImpl().printMe());
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project>
   <!-- ............   ............ -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test.namespace.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>test.namespace.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
   <!-- ............   ............ -->
</project>
```

**Question:**

1. Is this an expected behavior ?
2. Are there any maven plugin to detect this?
    `mvn dependency:analyze -DcheckDuplicateClasses` didn't help.

Thank you!

Comment: Didn't try it, so I don't dare to add this as an answer, but a quick search brought up this maven plugin: https://github.com/basepom/duplicate-finder-maven-plugin

(I think that the dependency plugin is just for duplicate dependencies, not for individual classes.)

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer the part "Is this an expected behavior ?": Yes, it's a feature, not a bug ;-)

In Java you can have multiple implementations of the "same" class (regarding its package and class name) in your classpath. That's why it is called class*path*: The first occurence "wins" and is chosen. So this can be used to overrule some implementations with others, just by placing the overruling implementation more to the front of the classpath.

In maven I would expect that in such a situation the dependency that comes first in the pom.xml is the one that "wins".

Especially for transitive dependencies this can be tricky to resolve, but you can [exclude specific (transitive) dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions).

Comment: Thank you @cyberbrain. I completely agree with the maven's dependency resolution order. So its not maven who handles this case but java ClassLoaders.